# Ubuntu GUI unable to login in a Virtual machine

Tags: gui

I have a issue with a newly installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS version on a vm .it never allows me to get in the GUI , the GUI pages accepts the account details and goes for a loop and comes back to the same page again.I have tried with all the user accounts available including the root and newly created accounts as well. But it does not allow me to get in. I am able to login to the SSH, telnet using the same credentials. SSH and telnet work fine, but GUI does not allow me to log in

Any suggestions please

Answer (score 0):

login in console mode using `ctrl + alt + f1` then try to remove `.Xauthority` file then restart lightdm

```
rm -rf .Xauthority
sudo service lightdm restart
```

if problem persists try to see whats in `~/.xsession-errors` files